# button collapse to the right in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a navigation bar which can collapse to the right. I've seen a few examples that collapses horizontally but that is not what I want. I have attached a basic mock below. Any idea would be appreciated.
[image: mock]

Comment: So you want your navigation to collapse from right to left and to just have a button on the left that represents your menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

going by your example picture it looks like you might have these placed somewhere in the page rather at the top of the page.

So may be if you consider using the popover. Place the nav button where you like and have the popover come up which ever side you need it to.

Take a look at **[this example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript#popovers-examples)** in Bootstrap here.

Does this help?

Comment: That definitely helped! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used popover as AngularJR said **[Check this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/dtd3a17e/1/)**

HTML part

```
  <button class="popper" data-toggle="popover">Pop me</button> 
<div class="popper-content hide"><nav class="nav">
    <ul>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subnav Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav></div>
```

Jquery Part

```
 $('.popper').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
    }
});
```